# How to move the center of MKMapView so that the default location icon goes to bottom center

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

I found some of the questions related to this on stackOverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301608/how-to-set-mkpinannotation-so-that-bottom-of-image-points-to-location-instead-of), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305876/how-to-move-the-center-position-of-google-map) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437048/ios-set-mkmapview-center-so-supplied-location-is-in-the-bottom-center) here. The last one actually worked but the problem is I'm using `heading` in `MapKit` I mean this `(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading`. SO the problem now it when I applied this solution:

```
MKCoordinateRegion oldRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.location.coordinate, 800.0f, 200.0f)];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerPointOfOldRegion = oldRegion.center;

    //Create a new center point (I added a quarter of oldRegion's latitudinal span)
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerPointOfNewRegion = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(centerPointOfOldRegion.latitude + oldRegion.span.latitudeDelta/5.0, centerPointOfOldRegion.longitude);

    //Create a new region with the new center point (same span as oldRegion)
    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerPointOfNewRegion, oldRegion.span);

    //Set the mapView's region
    [_mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:NO];
```

It successfully updates but as I move my phone and the accelometer is accessed it started a jerking effect between the newRegion and oldRegion. Any sggestions how?
**UPDATE**
 I found this method which was let me change the default image of the `userLocation annotation` and this has a property which I can set like `myAnnotaton.center` so any ideas here that this might work or how to set its center?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
            viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {


    if (annotation==(mapView.userLocation)) {
        MKAnnotationView *myAnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] init];

        myAnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker"];
        myAnotation.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

        return myAnotation;
    }
    else
    {
    return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting animated to yes in [_mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:NO]; so that it doesn't jerk.

Comment: @sanman it's not working... now the app is stuck it's now zooming inn as previously it was zooming in automatically... now it stucks for a time and then crashed... let me know if you want to see a specific piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a delegate method that will overwrite your default annotation.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
            viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {


    if (annotation==(mapView.userLocation)) {
        MKAnnotationView *myAnotation = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] init];

        myAnotation.image = self.userPointImage.image; //give any image here
        myAnotation.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, 250);

        return myAnotation;
    }
    else
    {
    return nil;
    }
}
```

The centerOffset will set the annotation to the bottom and the map will rotate accordingly to it